# Visual Studio references broken after nuget update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

We have strange behaviour in Visual Studio 2015.

If a teammate updates some nuget packages the other colleague is getting reference errors as shown in the picture. You are not able to build.

[image: error in references]

If we click on the erroneous reference the error disappears and everything works as expected. You are able to build.

[image: error in references disappears]

What is causing this error? This is quite annoying...

Anybody got a solution how to come over this?

Comment: What did your research show? Open the project file, inspect the hintpath. Chances are your colleague is updating the packages from another solution, or that they have mapped their package directory differently from your machine.

Comment: When we add a package via NudGet it will write a entry in the package.json - the other person who is facing the issue might not have a entry in that. Try to uninstall the package and reinstall and note when check-in to TFS have the solution file checked in or that specific project csproj is checked in.

Comment: path in <HintPath> is correct. we are using one solution file. if i unload the project and reload it, it also works.

Comment: What is the detailed error message your colleague got? Can you try following actions: Open TOOLS->Options->NuGet Package Manager in your VS, enable the two options:
1.            Visual Studio is configured to 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'
2.            Visual Studio is configured to 'Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio'

And then Re-open the solution again.

Comment: Both option are checked.

Comment: Is there any error message when you cannot run the build? Can you share the steps to reproduce this issue and what version control system are you using?

Comment: Triggered by your question we did some further investigation on the problem. Looks like "ReSharper Build" is causing the problem. We have disabled ReSharper and were able to build directly.